# CraftCMS upgrade to 3.0 loads blank page after upgrade

Tags: craftcms

I attempted to upgrade my Craft CMS 2.7 website to 3.0 following the instructions on:

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/upgrade.html#preparing-for-the-upgrade

I think that I have followed everything correctly, but my result was a blank page.  I have done some searching on this, and I am not getting any help.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I went to my apache error logs and found out that Craft CMS couldn't open the vendor/autoload.php file.  And, that was producing a blank page because CraftCMS couldn't even load anything because it couldn't load this file.

It ended up being a permissions issue.  I thought I have given it the right permission, and I had not.  In this case:

sudo chmod 774 -R vendor/

after that, I was getting the craft error messages and then I had to change the permissions on a few others that I thought I had already done.